# Testing react components and getting elements by className

Tags: reactjs, testing, classname, testing-library

Im wondering if putting new class name into html component only for readability and tests is ok.
Let's say we have this situation:

```
class ComponentOne extends React.Component {

    render(){
        <div>
           <div>
              <div className="lower">
                 {sometext}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

}
```

This classes are here only for better readability in browser and for better testing this component.
Like this :

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
it("Testing ComponentOne", ()=>{
   const { container } = render(<Component/>)
   const element = container.querySelector(".lower") // cleaner element searching
   // testing element's text here
})
```

Is it a bad idea to using "empty" class in React only for readability/debugging/testing ?
What is the best way to find elements while testing ?

Comment: I try pretty hard not to do it. If there's no text content or something else I can easily match with an existing RTL matcher than I wonder if I'm _really_ trying to test UI/UX or if I'm actually testing an implementation detail.

Comment: Ok, so if i have some nested html tags, without any pointers, and i want to test changing style on click of the most nested of it i should go for the css selector/ xpath or something else ? The point is that if something will change whole selector should be changed, but if i have some classes (etc) tests wont change if structure will change.

Answer (score 3):

If some one looking for a solution to select by **Id** or **Class** in **React Testing Library** with **Screen**.
Then check this

```
class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <div data-testid='main-component'>
           <div>
              <div className="lower">
                 {sometext}
                 <span id='spanid'> sometext2</span>
                 <div className="lower2">
                    {sometext3}
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Then we can achieve this:

```
  import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
        it("Testing ComponentOne", ()=>{
           render(<Component/>)
    // testing element's text here
           const element = screen.getByTestId('main-component').querySelector(".lower") //select lower div
           expect(element).toHaveTextContent('sometext') 
    //Testing with Id
           const spanElement = screen.getByTestId('main-component').querySelector("#spanid") //select lower div
           expect(spanElement).toHaveTextContent('sometext2') 
    //Testing with nested class 
           const nestedElement = screen.getByTestId('main-component').querySelector(".lower.lower2") //select lower2 div
           expect(nested).toHaveTextContent('sometext3') class 
        })
```

You can test any class or Id base test by add a **data-testid** to the parent div on component level or by adding the test id in each required tags.
Then `getByTestId & querySelector`
I hope it will help you.

Comment: You assume that the developer has edit access to the tested component's structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector(...)` to query anything that has been mounted. See the example below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Query by ID', () => {
  it('Using querySelector', async () => {
    render(
      <div className="componentClassName" id="componentId">
        component
      </div>
    );
    const component = document.querySelector('#componentId');

    expect(component).toHaveClass('componentClassName');
  });
});
```